# Why is this code glacial?

Tags: c#

I would have expected this code to execute with speeed, but for a list of 5000 elements it ran for in excess of 20 minutes before I killed it.

Is it because of list.contains()?

Any ideas?

```
     public static int PNum(int N)
     {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            result.Add(i * (3 * i - 1) / 2);

        int len = result.Count;
        int minDiff = 10000;
        int sum = 0, diff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= len - 1; j++)
            {
                diff = result[j] - result[i];
                if (result.Contains(diff))
                {
                    sum = result[i] + result[j];
                    if (result.Contains(sum))
                    {
                        if (diff < minDiff)
                            diff = minDiff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return minDiff;
    }
```

Comment: I think you may have diff and minDiff switched, shouldn't it be `if (diff < minDiff) minDiff = diff;` ?  Otherwise, you'll always return what you set minDiff to originally, 10000 in this case.

Comment: @Tory - Hi Tory, you're right, though the version I'm currently running simply does a `return diff` on the `if` condition.

Answer (score 6):

`N` is 5000. So, your outer loop runs for 5000 iterations, the inner loop for 5000 iterations, and the `List<T>.Contains` iterates over every element and so it also does 5000 iterations worth of work.

So, your loop is doing around 5000<sup>3</sup> = 125,000,000,000 operations at a minimum, which will take quite some time.

The problem is indeed your use of `List.Contains`. Use a `HashSet` instead (or in addition) to get O(1) `Contains` tests.

Comment: The Outer and Inner loops should only total (5000 * 4999)/2 = 12,497,500.  But yeah, it is both of the List.Contains.  Each of those is having to check each item until it hits an equal value (which may never happen, so it would have to go through all of them to find out).

Comment: Another significant optimization would be to change the inner loop control to `for (int j = i + 1; j <= len - 1 && j < i + minDiff; j++)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I don't think that would work? `minDiff` is the minimum of `result[i] - result[j]`.

Comment: @Tory: I counted the work done by `List.Contains` in that calculation.

Comment: @nneonneo right, I should have said `for (int j = i + 1; j <= len - 1 && result[j] - result[i] < minDiff; j++)`.  But, as it turns out, even corrected it doesn't help because `minDiff` never actually goes down.